# Notice: Undefined variable: ids in

Tags: php, variables, undefined

i have a script that works fine for years and suddenly i face this problem : 
 please check the code and mend any solutionplease. any kind of help willbe appreciated.

```
Notice: Undefined variable: ids in /home/content/a/t/a/ataasaid1/html/category.php on line 4

Notice: Undefined variable: id in /home/content/a/t/a/ataasaid1/html/category.php on line 5

Notice: Use of undefined constant image - assumed 'image' in /home/content/a/t/a/ataasaid1/html/category.php on line 11

Notice: Use of undefined constant video - assumed 'video' in /home/content/a/t/a/ataasaid1/html/category.php on line 15

Notice: Use of undefined constant sound - assumed 'sound' in /home/content/a/t/a/ataasaid1/html/category.php on line 19
```

the code in file category.php is :

```
<?
  error_reporting(E_ALL | E_STRICT);
  ini_set("display_errors", 1);    
$id1=$ids;
$id2=$id;
                      include('config.php');

                    $result= mysql_query("SELECT * FROM products where id like '$id1' ;");
                    $row=mysql_fetch_array ($result);
                    $type=$row['type'];
                    if($type==image)
                    {
                    include('categories.php');
}
else if($type==video)
{
include('categories2.php');
}
else if($type==sound)
{
include('categories3.php');
}
?>
```

i use the url like:

/category.php?id=64&ids=305

thank you in advanced

Comment: I don't see where $ids and $id are defined...And, you missed quotes around video and sound : 'video', 'sound'.

Comment: 1) Your line 4 and 5 are different from what you posted here. 2) You're trying to access undefined constants in your code. Change `if($type==image)` to `if($type == "video")` (replace all similar occurrences)

Comment: i use the url like: /category.php?id=64&ids=305

Answer (score 0):

write like this:

```
if($type=="video")

else if($type=="sound")
```

Comment: Why we shouldn't use as if($type==video)

else if($type==sound)

Comment: PHP take it as constant.

Comment: Ok then is it effects the comparision operation...

Answer (score 0):

Are you looking for

```
$id1=$_GET["ids"];
$id2=$_GET["id"];
```

or

```
$id1=$_POST["ids"];
$id2=$_POST["id"];
```

???

Comment: i use the url like:

/category.php?id=64&ids=305

Comment: @user2956413: so you have to use $_GET as I suggested.

Answer (score 0):

This error basically means that you're trying to use the variables `$ids` and `$id`, even though they do not exist. You need to define a variable before you can use it. Otherwise, you will get notices like this and your application will end up being a buggy mess. Because those two variables are not set and you are assigning them to other variables:

```
$id1 = $ids;
$id2 = $id;
```

Those variables are now useless, which means that your SQL query is also useless:

```
$result= mysql_query("SELECT * FROM products where id like '$id1' ;");
```

because `$id1` isn't anything.

Comment: i use the url like:

/category.php?id=64&ids=305